# Putting a bunch of name into a JSON format in python with regex

Tags: python, json

I want to put a lot of name which are in a file like this: Anna Jay Lea Arthur and I want them between these marks:
["Anna",
"Jay,"
"Lea",
"Arthur",

in the json format so I've tried that but nothing happens, does somebody have an idea please?

```
f1 = open('names.json', 'w')
regex = regex.compile('^([A-Za-z])+)$')
for line in f1:
    regex.sub('['{}'],'.format(line))
f1.close()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does `f1 = open('names.json', 'r')` and then `print(re.findall(r'^[A-Za-z]+$', f1.read(), re.M))` work correctly?

Comment: Why are you trying to use regular expressions to parse and/or generate JSON? Use the `json` module.

Comment: Do you want to read the file and print into STDOUT?

Comment: thanks for your answer guys! Sorry Wiktor but it didn't worked nothing happened in the file, and I don't want to use the json module because my names should be in list and there are a lot of them so I really wanted to use regex so it does it faster

Comment: So, you really have a JSON and your regex is just messed up.

Answer (score 1):

Define the list you want, then write it to a file using `json.dump`:

```
import json


names = ['Anna', 'Jay', 'Lea', 'Arthur']

with open('names.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(names, f)
```

If you are trying to read a JSON array from a file,

```
with open('names.json') as f:
    names = json.load(f)
```